# What is the best way to join the same table twice in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, database-design, database-performance

The performance with the second join on the same table is degraded nearly half

```
SELECT * FROM party_party_relationship AS ppr 
    LEFT JOIN party_role AS r1 ON r1.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid
    LEFT JOIN party_role AS r2 ON r2.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid_related
```

**Performance with first Join**

```
"Hash Left Join  (cost=288.18..547.72 rows=10972 width=144) (actual time=5.281..17.781 rows=11192 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (ppr.party_role_uid = r1.party_role_uid)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on party_party_relationship ppr  (cost=0.00..230.72 rows=10972 width=98) (actual time=0.020..2.438 rows=11192 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=181.97..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=5.186..5.187 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 823kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on party_role r1  (cost=0.00..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=0.010..2.073 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.472 ms"
"Execution Time: 18.765 ms"
```

[image: With two join]

**Performance with the second join on the same table almost doubled**

```
"Hash Left Join  (cost=576.37..864.71 rows=10972 width=190) (actual time=9.871..31.986 rows=11192 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (ppr.party_role_uid_related = r2.party_role_uid)"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=288.18..547.72 rows=10972 width=144) (actual time=5.163..18.437 rows=11192 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (ppr.party_role_uid = r1.party_role_uid)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on party_party_relationship ppr  (cost=0.00..230.72 rows=10972 width=98) (actual time=0.015..2.735 rows=11192 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=181.97..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=5.091..5.092 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 823kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on party_role r1  (cost=0.00..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=0.008..2.030 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=181.97..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=4.644..4.644 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 823kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on party_role r2  (cost=0.00..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=0.014..1.810 rows=9946 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.925 ms"
"Execution Time: 32.920 ms"
```

[image: With one join]

The above query is just a part of the whole query.

```
SELECT * FROM party_party_relationship AS ppr 
    INNER JOIN party_role AS r1 ON r1.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid
        INNER JOIN party AS p1 ON p1.party_uid = r1.party_uid
                LEFT JOIN party_name AS n1 ON n1.party_uid = p1.party_uid AND n1.end_date IS NULL
                LEFT JOIN business_number AS b1 ON b1.party_uid = p1.party_uid AND b1.business_number_cd = p1.business_number_cd AND b1.end_date IS NULL

    INNER JOIN party_role AS r2 ON r2.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid_related
        INNER JOIN party AS p2 ON p2.party_uid = r2.party_uid
                LEFT JOIN party_name AS n2 ON n2.party_uid = p2.party_uid AND n2.end_date IS NULL
                LEFT JOIN business_number AS b2 ON b2.party_uid = p2.party_uid AND b2.business_number_cd = p2.business_number_cd AND b2.end_date IS NULL
                
                WHERE ppr.case_uid = 9
```

**Execution Plan**

```
"Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1113.46..3576.37 rows=915 width=772) (actual time=19.687..76.911 rows=919 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1113.31..3270.33 rows=915 width=694) (actual time=19.616..56.253 rows=919 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (n1.end_date IS NULL)"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1113.03..2415.51 rows=915 width=547) (actual time=19.588..51.236 rows=915 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (r1.party_uid = p2.party_uid)"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=856.60..2156.68 rows=915 width=481) (actual time=15.192..45.391 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (ppr.party_role_uid_related = r2.party_role_uid)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=568.42..1866.09 rows=915 width=435) (actual time=9.743..38.415 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=568.27..1560.05 rows=915 width=357) (actual time=9.665..17.956 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=567.99..705.23 rows=915 width=210) (actual time=9.639..12.460 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (r1.party_uid = p1.party_uid)"
"                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=311.56..446.40 rows=915 width=144) (actual time=5.314..7.056 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (ppr.party_role_uid = r1.party_role_uid)"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on party_party_relationship ppr  (cost=23.38..155.81 rows=915 width=98) (actual time=0.111..0.536 rows=915 loops=1)"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: (insolvency_case_uid = 9)"
"                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=18"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ixfk_party_party_relationship_insolvency_case  (cost=0.00..23.15 rows=915 width=0) (actual time=0.097..0.097 rows=926 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (insolvency_case_uid = 9)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=181.97..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=5.149..5.149 rows=9960 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 824kB"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on party_role r1  (cost=0.00..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=0.009..1.979 rows=9960 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=161.19..161.19 rows=7619 width=66) (actual time=4.290..4.290 rows=7449 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 701kB"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on party p1  (cost=0.00..161.19 rows=7619 width=66) (actual time=0.013..1.680 rows=7449 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using ixfk_party_name_party on party_name n1  (cost=0.28..0.92 rows=1 width=147) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=915)"
"                                      Index Cond: (party_uid = p1.party_uid)"
"                                      Filter: (end_date IS NULL)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                          ->  Index Scan using ex_business_number_end_date on business_number b1  (cost=0.15..0.32 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=915)"
"                                Index Cond: ((party_uid = p1.party_uid) AND (business_number_cd = p1.business_number_cd))"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=181.97..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=5.293..5.293 rows=9960 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 824kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on party_role r2  (cost=0.00..181.97 rows=8497 width=46) (actual time=0.010..1.799 rows=9960 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=161.19..161.19 rows=7619 width=66) (actual time=4.313..4.314 rows=7449 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 701kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on party p2  (cost=0.00..161.19 rows=7619 width=66) (actual time=0.011..1.587 rows=7449 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using ixfk_party_name_party on party_name n2  (cost=0.28..0.92 rows=1 width=147) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=915)"
"              Index Cond: (party_uid = p2.party_uid)"
"  ->  Index Scan using ex_business_number_end_date on business_number b2  (cost=0.15..0.32 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=919)"
"        Index Cond: ((party_uid = p2.party_uid) AND (business_number_cd = p2.business_number_cd))"
"Planning Time: 4.499 ms"
"Execution Time: 77.433 ms"
```

Plan in Graph

[image: Part of Execution plan - graph]

Is there any better way to do it? The table is expected to grow very fast.

Comment: Your query retrieves all rows from both tables. This is going to be slow if the tables grow. There is not much you can do about. One thing you can try is to only join once `LEFT JOIN party_role AS r ON r.party_role_uid = any[ppr.party_role_uid, ppr.party_role_uid_related]` - which is a slightly different result, but it at least removes one Seq Scan

Comment: Which of the execution plans belongs to the full query?

Comment: The last block (`Planning Time: 4.499 ms & Execution Time: 77.433 ms`) just now added.

Comment: The whole query joins two party_role by "INNER JOIN", but the part of query uses "LEFT JOIN".  Is it correct that the query uses "LEFT JOIN"? Is there unmatched data in party_role_uid of party_role?
In "INNER JOIN party AS p2 ON p2.party_uid = r1.party_uid" and "LEFT JOIN party_name AS n2 ON n2.party_uid = p2.party_uid AND n1.end_date IS NULL", r1 and n1 are used. Is it correct?
If these are incorrect, then there is a way to use WITH clause to join tables party_role, party, party_name and business_number in advance. That way you can reduce the number of joins.

Comment: What indexes do the tables have?

Answer (score 3):

It is not weird that joining the same table an extra time (and thus doing twice as much work) takes twice as long. Your question is a bit problematic, however, because it always depends - a lot. I have a few remarks, though, that could hopefully help you a little:

- You're selecting all (`*`) inside the SELECT. This might have been for the sake of this example, but for me, changing `*` to the specific columns I want can shave off up to 20% of a query, depending on the number of columns and the number of tables. An example from my own database:

```
Gather  (cost=43909.56..166695.17 rows=160724 width=704) (actual time=767.822..2555.382 rows=159158 loops=1)

becomes

Gather  (cost=38729.56..136383.17 rows=160724 width=65) (actual time=354.540..1603.087 rows=159158 loops=1)
```

- You're joining `party` to get to `party_name` and `business_number`, and I guess a party probably only has one of each. You're also filtering on something akin to an `id`, so you probably want to return only a few rows. Supposing that you need only one thing from `party_name` and `business_number`, you could move that to a scalar query inside `SELECT`. Then, you don't need to `JOIN` there any more, and because a query without results returns `NULL`, you also don't need to `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT ppr.case_uid
       (SELECT b.business_number
        FROM business_number AS b
        WHERE b.business_number_cd = p1.business_number_cd
          AND b.end_date IS NULL
       ) as p1_business_number,
       (SELECT n.party_name
        FROM party_uid AS n
        WHERE n.party_uid = p1.party_uid
          AND n.end_date IS NULL
       ) as p1_party_name,
       (SELECT b.business_number
        FROM business_number AS b
        WHERE b.business_number_cd = p2.business_number_cd
          AND b.end_date IS NULL
       ) as p2_business_number,
       (SELECT n.party_name
        FROM party_uid AS n
        WHERE n.party_uid = p2.party_uid
          AND n.end_date IS NULL
       ) as p2_party_name
FROM party_party_relationship AS ppr
INNER JOIN party_role AS r1 ON r1.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid
INNER JOIN party AS p1 ON p1.party_uid = r1.party_uid
INNER JOIN party_role AS r2 ON r2.party_role_uid = ppr.party_role_uid_related
INNER JOIN party AS p2 ON p2.party_uid = r2.party_uid
WHERE ppr.case_uid = 9
```

- If you don't need anything else from `party`, you can also remove that `JOIN` and move it inside the scalar subqueries for `business_number`. You already know `party_uid` from `party_role`, after all.